# Как через XML нарисовать полосы разных цветов?

Tags: android, xml

Нужно создать вот такой фон для layout: [image: фон]

Как нарисовать такие углы через xml? Можно ли это реализовать по-другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**custom_background.xml:**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

            <solid android:color="#FFF" />

        </shape>

    </item>

    <item>

        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:toDegrees="45">

            <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                <stroke
                    android:color="#717171"
                    android:width="15dp" />

                <solid android:color="#484848" />

            </shape>

        </rotate>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**test_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="3.5" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TEXT VIEW TEST"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А каким образом можно установить этот **test_layout.xml** как фон для других **layout** и размещать поверх другие элементы?

Comment: @zepelinjam фон `layout`'ов `android:background="@drawable/custom_background"` ну и не забывайте про `android:scaleX="1.5"` и `android:scaleY="3.5"`  - это важно

Comment: Это понятно. Просто когда я добавляю в этот `layout` другие элементы, например `TextView`, то они по какой-то причине не отображаются. А когда убираю `android:background="@drawable/custom_background"`, `android:scaleX="1.5"` и `android:scaleY="3.5"`, то всё работает.

Comment: @zepelinjam обновил ответ, все дело было в растяжке: `android:scaleX="1.5" и android:scaleY="3.5"`. Пока придётся использовать отдельный виджет view с растяжкой для фона, т.е. растягиваем только одну вьюху, а не весь layout с содержимым. А почему так долго не писали про это?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй  градиент на нужный лаяут задать как  background

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="45"
    android:useLevel="true"
    android:endColor="#21506C"
    android:startColor="#161840"
    android:type="linear" />
```

Comment: Градиент и полосы это не одно и то же.